# Possible to Hot Reload With flutter run Command?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm currently making an app for Android with Flutter, and I'm using google-mobile-ads package to show banner ads.
My environment is VScode & Android emurator by Android Studio.

To run this project Execute this command:

```
$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Not with Play button.

However if I run with this command, hot reload is disabled. Any edits don't make any changes.

flutter doctor -v;

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.6.0-5.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.282], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.6.0-5.2.pre at D:\src\flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 400608f101 (8 weeks ago), 2021-09-15 15:50:26 -0700
    • Engine revision 1d521d89d8
    • Dart version 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.2.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\yukik\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44

• No issues found!
```

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `flutter run` you should be able to hot reload pressing `r` and to hot restart using `R`. Just press them in the terminal where you've used `flutter run`.

If I remember correctly, launching `flutter run` you should get all these info on the console as a message when starting!

Comment: As you said I got message. Thanks!

Comment: I didnt understand how flutter run and auto reload if I change code and didnt press R or r in terminal?